# How to separate the string twice?

Tags: python

I want to remove semi-colons, parentheses and dashes at the same time. How to do it with `split()`?
For example, converting (shipment_id[s]-ef234;sender[s]-Taiwan Electronics Co) into `["shipment_id[s]", "ef234", "sender[s]", "Taiwan Electronics Co"]`  What if the item contain dashes already like"JB HI-FI". How to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be super simple to achieve this with `regex`.

```
import re
pattern = r'[-|;]'

string = 'shipment_id[s]-ef234;sender[s]-Taiwan Electronics Co'

re.split(pattern, string)
#['shipment_id[s]', 'ef234', 'sender[s]', 'Taiwan Electronics Co']
```

If the `()` are included, we can simply add them to our pattern and pass it via a list comprehension to only include values that are `True`.

```
string = '(shipment_id[s]-ef234;sender[s]-Taiwan Electronics Co)'
pattern = r'[-|;|\(|\)]'
print([match for match in re.split(pattern, string) if match])

#['shipment_id[s]', 'ef234', 'sender[s]', 'Taiwan Electronics Co']
```

Comment: You'll have extra work if you keep the starting and ending `(` and `)` as the question asks because of the empty strings it will create.

Comment: Simple list comprehension can remove empty strings if that's really a huge concern. Or just use `strip` to remove the parenthesis before doing the `split`.

Comment: Added to account for `()` @Mark

Comment: I wonder if `re.findall(r'[^;()-]+',s)` or similar would be simpler.

Comment: What if the item which contain dashes like "JB HI-FI". How to do with that?